# How to stop burp/fiddler proxies from accessing the request/response?

Tags: appsec, proxy

Im a beginner in WASA.
I just wanted to know if "certificate pinning" can avoid request/response from getting captured by proxies like burp/fiddler?
If not so, then if I want my request and response not to be captured by proxies then what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll just quote the downvote tip: "This question does not show any research effort."

Answer (score 0):

If the CA used by burp/fiddler to intercept HTTPS connections was explicitly added to your browser/OS as trusted then pinning protection will be disabled by current browsers to allow legal SSL interception (you trust the proxy CA).

If you did not install the proxy CA as trusted then you'll probably not even need pinning to detect the MITM. But pinning is helpful if somebody has managed to get a publicly accepted CA to sign its own certificates (i.e. hacked a CA or misuse of intermediate CA's).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you want your requests and responses to be captured by an intercepting proxy? Certificate pinning will make it a bit harder, but in the end the user agent (the browser) is under the control of the user. If they really want to see the traffic then they can just use a user agent that doesnt support certificate pinning. You cannot rely on absolute secrecy for your services security or to protect your intelectual property.